# Выравнивание SWF внутри DIV по вертикали и по горизонтали

Tags: flash, html, swf

возможно ли?

имеем:

```
<div>
<object> ...swf...</object>
</div>
```

Можно ли выровнить флешку внутри дива?

Answer (score 3):

У дива поставить:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

UPD: если по вертикали ещё..

- Вариант раз.

Если известна ширина и высота, то можно вот так. Стиль объекта object:

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -(width/2)px;
margin-top: -(height/2)px;
position: absolute;
```

Стиль родительского дива:

```
position: relative;
```

- Вариант 2.

Можно с использованием js - получить размеры, проставить отступы. Если js выключен - будет бе. Зато в ином случае всё будет ня.

- Вариант 3.

Стиль родительского блока:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
```

Но это не очень кроссбраузерно .з. Возможно, для надёжности (и для старых браузеров), потребуется ещё один внешний div с display: table;

Comment: это по горизонтали же, и во всех браузерах будет работать? а что по вертикали?

Comment: То ли сразу не было про вертикаль, то ли я не заметил, потому так и ответил =) Добавил upd.

Comment: размеры флешки могут быть любые

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас придумаю ещё вариант =)

Answer (score 0):

Если известна высота флешки, то по вертикали надо проставить правильные паддинги. Если неизвестна, то

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

вам в помощь.

Comment: если высота неизвестна, каким образом её встраивать в <object>? там ведь нужно указывать ширину и высоту

Comment: Высота может быть переменной, либо указываться в процентах.

Answer (score 0):

Может это поможет

```
<style> .object-wrapper {position: relative; left: XXpx; right: XXpx; top: XXpx;}
    </style><div class="object-wrapper">  ...swf... </div>
```

Comment: что такое XXpx? Размеры флешки неизвестны изначально.